# Abstract method parameter contravariance in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In a recent C# version (9.0) we got a nice feature called `Covariant returns` which gave us the possibility to specify a more specific return type in a derived class method override:

[Covariant returns](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#covariant-returns)

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract Food GetFood();
    ...
}
class Tiger : Animal
{
    public override Meat GetFood() => ...;
}
```

Why C# doesn't give us a possibility to specify a more specific method parameter type in a derived class method override? For example, if I declare the base class abstract method `Eat` that accepts a base parameter type `Food`, why I'm not able to override the method with a more specific parameter type `Meat` (derived from `Food`)?

What I want is following:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public abstract void Eat(Food f);
    ...
}
class Tiger : Animal
{
    public override void Eat(Meat m) => ...;
}
```

If I have the instance of `Tiger` I want to be able to pass only `Meat` (subclass of `Food`) as a `Eat` method input parameter. Also, if we want to change the direction and in `Tiger` class method override specify a more generic parameter than the one in abstract class (e.g. `Food` in abstract class and `EnergySource` in `Tiger` class), that doesn't work in C# too.

After some research and tests I was not able to find a way to do this in C#. To be more specific, I don't think C# support such thing, but I would like to validate my conclusion.

What is currently possible is something like this:

```
abstract class Animal<T> where T : Food
{
    public abstract void Eat(T f);
}

class Tiger : Animal<Meat>
{
    public override void Eat(Meat f)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This is fine if the derived class doesn't need to do a lot of overrides. Whenever we want to introduce a new method override and if that new method wants to have a specific parameter type we will need to extend the Animal<T,...> for new generics which is not optimal.

Answer (score 3):

Because this would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle which basically says that you must be able to replace a supertype with a subtype.

In particular, if this works:

```
Animal animal = ChooseRandomAnimal();
animal.Eat(someFlower);     // works, because Flower is a subtype of Food
```

Then this must work as well:

```
Animal animal = new Tiger();
animal.Eat(someFlower);     // we just fed plants to your tiger
```

---

The theoretical background for this problem is that return types are ***co**variant*, but method parameters are ***contra**variant*. This means that *narrowing* a method parameter type in a subtype does not work (see example above), but *widening* would be OK (...at least from a type system perspective. It's still not supported by C#).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, I was first reading the theoretical part and that was also my conclusion and I agree with you. That would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle but the "legal" approach where the more generic type is used in a subtype is also not supported in C#. I mean, at least I can't compile such approach.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you could implement food using Generics and instantiate a food object of type Meat, Flower, etc..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

From there in you handle how they eat which food based on animal type.